# Rearrange a CSV file

Tags: csv

I need to know what is an easy way to convert a csv file without using excel.
There is a csv that I need to rearrange positions, change some fields format, etc.
How can I do it?

Comment: Can you use OpenOffice ?

Comment: No, because this needs to run automatically every 2 hours and opening an application to get this data and formatting simply is too complicated to schedule it using a spreadsheet tool, i need something better than that.

Comment: Is this question about the same problem you were attempting to solve in [last week's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025574/change-positions-on-a-csv-file)? The description of this question seems like it fits as a scant summary of the other question. Either way, asking how to use an unspecified tool to make unspecified changes to an unspecified CSV file in an unspecified environment with any other requirements and details also unspecified makes this a very broad question. We do know that you want the solution to be "easy", at least, but that doesn't make it more answerable.

Comment: Yes is the same question, after fighting with automating excel and powerquery failing because it was running automated, I managed it to make it work, but I dont like to use excel for this, is too slow and unstable. Good thing is that Powershell was super easy to learn. I am almost done.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you need to do some scripting!  PowerShell,c#,vba, etc...

Comment: Exactly that is what I need to know, what would be an advisable way of doing it without having so much programming skills.

Comment: Well it depends on your experience, it's hard to say... They are all the same, syntax is a little different. For your case I would say PowerShell !

Comment: Ok got it, I read and learned Powershell so my script is ready and works!

Comment: Just one thing I have not been able to figure out, how do I duplicate a column? I have
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4 and I want to export to Column1,Column2,Column1,Column3,Column4 sorry for all the posts, I hit enter and it just keeps creating new posts I dont know where to turn this off.